# Как конвертировать файл из URL на BLOB для передачи через Websocket (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, websocket, ionic, blob

Не могу передать файл на сервер Websocket. Есть ссылка на файл (http://localhost:8100/assets/audios/english_test.wav). В интернете есть решения для JS, но для TS не сработало (или я неправильно сделал). Есть простой способ передачи файл из URL на сервер Websocket?

ИСХОДНИКИ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу с Fetch. Раньше не знал про этого метода. Теперь буду знать!

```
public recognition() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8100/assets/audios/english_test.wav')
      .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
      .then(blob => {
        this.sendToWebsocket(blob);
      });
}
```